# Using Tuples in Report Builder Custom Code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, tuples, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to use a Tuple in the Custom Code bit of Report Builder. It's complaining about this line:

```
    MyTable.Add(staffCode, New Tuple(Of Date, String)(absDate, GenerateRandomString(8, TRUE)))
```

With the Error Message "There is an error on line 40 of custom code: [BC30002] Type 'Tuple' is not defined, and I really don't understand why. Tuple is obviously an object in VB so I cannot fathom why report builder is complaining about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was wrong, it's not .NET framework. Help still needed pls :)

Comment: Well, looks like Tuple was introduced in .net 4.0.   Are you referencing that in your project?